ROS 2 Jazzy DDS communication from docker container on macOS to raspberri pi 5 ROS 2 Jazzy
problem: 

Cannot communicate from ROS2 Jazzy on raspberry pi to ROS2 Jazzy on docker container on MacOS

Host

MacOS Version: 15.1
Container Image: arm64v8/ros:jazzy
Docker Version: 4.34.3
Docker Host Networking: Enabled
Docker Subnet: 192.168.65.0/24
Ping from Raspberry Pi: Successful

Robot

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Ping from Mac: Successful
IP Address: 192.168.2.9

Docker Run Command
docker run -it --rm  \
--network host \
--pid=host \
--ipc=host \
--entrypoint \
/bin/bash \
my_jazzy

DDS Server init
rover@rover-pi:~/Fast-DDS/build$ fastdds discovery --server-id 0
### Server is running ###
Participant Type:   SERVER
Security:           NO
Server ID:          0
Server GUID prefix: 44.53.00.5f.45.50.52.4f.53.49.4d.41
Server Addresses:   UDPv4:[0.0.0.0]:11811

env var pi
rover@rover-pi:~$ env | grep ROS_
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_AUTOMATIC_DISCOVERY_RANGE=SUBNET
ROS_DISTRO=jazzy
ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=192.168.2.9:11811

env var mac
dev@docker-desktop:~$ env | grep ROS_
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1
ROS_AUTOMATIC_DISCOVERY_RANGE=SUBNET
ROS_DISTRO=jazzy
ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=192.168.2.9:11811


cammands tried:
pi
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args --remap __node:=talker_discovery_server

ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker

mac
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener --ros-args --remap __node:=listener_discovery_server

ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener


Did you forget to set ROS_DOMAIN_ID on raspberry pi?

yes indeed I did, but that was not it. It still doesnt work
I must also mention that i have enabled host networking from docker dashboard>settings>resources>network

adding RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp on both host & pi didn't work either

I don't recall needing a DDS Discovery Server back on foxy when I tried something similar. I am guessing the DDS multicasts are not getting where they need to be. Maybe try adding their respective IPs to the env variable ROS_STATIC_IP link.

doesn't work ROS_STATIC_PEERS either. Tey do not communicate in subnet

I think the issue is similar to https://answers.ros.org/question/311185/ros2-dds-communication-between-different-layer3-subnets/ -- seems like it's either static endpoint discovery, or configure the DDS discovery server

My setup includes macOS, docker, Ubuntu 24.04 vm on UTM on macOS, Raspberry Pi 5 running Ubuntu 24.04. The Ubuntu images are for 64-bit ARMv8 processors and can be found here. The ros images are ROS2 Jazzy Jalisco for Arm and can be found here.
Ubuntu 24.04 on Raspberry Pi 5(Running ROS2 Jazzy)

Discovery Server (it could also be in container)

Docker container on Ubuntu 24.04 VM in UTM on macOS

listener

Docker container on Ubuntu 24.04 on Raspberry Pi 5

talker

Please find settings and commands below:
pi5

Terminal 1: run the dds server fastdds discovery -i 0 -l 192.168.2.9 -p 11811 192.168.2.9 is the IP address of the device running the server
Terminal 2: run docker talker container sudo docker run -it --rm  --network host  --ipc=host    --entrypoint /bin/bash  <your ROS2 image>

talker host must have ENV variable set to:
ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=192.168.2.9:11811
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1

listener host must have the following:
FASTRTPS_DEFAULT_PROFILES_FILE=./super_client_configuration_file.xml
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1

listener must have config file stored somewhere (and passed to FASTRTPS_DEFAULT_PROFILES_FILE)
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <dds>
     <profiles xmlns="http://www.eprosima.com/XMLSchemas/fastRTPS_Profiles">
         <participant profile_name="super_client_profile" is_default_profile="true">
             <rtps>
                 <builtin>
                     <discovery_config>
                         <discoveryProtocol>SUPER_CLIENT</discoveryProtocol>
                         <discoveryServersList>
                             <RemoteServer prefix="44.53.00.5f.45.50.52.4f.53.49.4d.41">
                                 <metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                                     <locator>
                                         <udpv4>
                                             <address>192.168.2.9</address> <!-- IP address of the Discovery server that  is running-->
                                             <port>11811</port><!-- port of Discovery server that is running-->
                                         </udpv4>
                                     </locator>
                                 </metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                             </RemoteServer>
                         </discoveryServersList>
                     </discovery_config>
                 </builtin>
             </rtps>
         </participant>
     </profiles>
 </dds>

